# .NET Core: ViewModel attributes are not rendered

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application using the Razor view engine. First and foremost I tried to look for solutions over the internet and here in StackOverFlow but any of these could solve my issue. Let's see what we are facing:

I have a relative simple view model for a customer:

```
namespace MokaKukaMap.Application.Customers.ViewModels.Models
{
    public class CustomerViewModel
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Név")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Telefonszám")]
        [Required]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see the `Name` and `PhoneNumber` properties have the attribute `Display` specified.
My corresponding partial view (`_NewCustomer.cshtml`) is the following:

```
@model MokaKukaMap.Application.Customers.ViewModels.Models.CustomerViewModel

<div class="col-lg-5 basic-surronder">
    <form asp-controller="NewCustomer" asp-action="NewCustomer" class="well">
        <div id="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class=""></label>
                <div class="">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control">
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Name" class="text-danger"> </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class=""></label>
                <div class="">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class="form-control">
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="">
                <input type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" value="Új ügyfél hozzáadása" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So far so good. As as I already mentioned I use this view as a partial view, so I include her in the `NewCustomer.cshtml` main view with the following line:

```
@Html.Partial("_NewCustomer")
```

The `_NewCustomer.cshtml` is located in the standard Views/Shared folder. What I would like do is to place this partial view into a specific folder, namely to the Customers/Views folder. In order to solve this I made a `CustomerViewLocationExpander`, like the following:

```
public class CustomViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        var viewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Customers/Views/{0}.cshtml", 
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{0}.cshtml",
        };
        return viewLocationFormats;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        context.Values["customviewlocation"] = nameof(CustomViewLocationExpander);
    }
}
```

Which is configured in Startup.cs:

```
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CustomViewLocationExpander()));
```

My issue is the following: If the `_NewCustomer.cshtml` is located in the Views/Shared folder, everything works fine. But If I place it to my custom Customer/Views folder, the name of the properties are not displayed/rendered, and also the validation attributes are not working at all. The two input fields are rendered because I see the following form:
[image]

What I already tried to solve my issue, (but none of them helped):

- Configuring the view location in the startup

  ```
  services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o => o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Customers/Views/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension));
  ```
- Using the absolute path when I include the partial view:

  ```
  @Html.Partial("~/Customers/Views/_NewCustomer.cshtml")
  ```
- Creating a folder named 'Shared' in my 'Customer' folder and place my partial view there: Customer/Views/Shared
- Removing all the 'bin' and 'obj' folders, clean then rebuild the solution

Furthermore I realized that if the partial view is located in the custom folder, then the VS2017 (IntelliSense) does not recognize the asp-net-core specific html tags, for example the `<form asp-controller=` is not highlighted in green, only if the view is located in the Shared folder.

Additional info:

My folder structure looks like the following:
[image]

What do you think where the problem lies? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? I could do it without a problem, but I used a different folder structure.. not sure if you can change your structure or not.

Comment: Also, did you configured your `CustomViewLocationExpander` in the `ConfigureServices` method?

Comment: @jpgrassi thanks for your comments! The `CustomViewLocationExpander` is configured in the services. As for the folder structure, I added an image of it. And yes, I am flexible to change the folder structure but I would like to put the partial view into that custom folder (Customer/Views) described in the question. Or you have any better idea about it?

Comment: I see.. what I managed to do is "rename" the View folders to something like "Features". Will try to reproduce in your structure and see if it also works.

Comment: @jpgrassi thanks! Additional info which may be relevant: my view model  `CustomerViewModel` is located in another project, namely in the 'MokaKukaMap.Application' project which is my application layer. As for the views, they are sitting in the 'MokaKukaMap' project which is my presentation layer! DDD for the win :)

Comment: Check my answer.. it's working for me but it's a bit beyond your current setup. I can put it on github if you want to try it out. Just let me know.

Comment: @jpgrassi To be honest I like your solution and the arguments you made! I agree with you! I will change my project then then if it is done and works I accept your answer! Could you please put you solution to a github repo, would be helpful to adjust my project.

Comment: @jpgrassi Regarding your questions: Container is a not related to docker, it is a container which is used to transfer building materials from one place to another. As for DDD, you are right, the view model is just a plain anemic model. I was just referring to the standrad layers of DDD: Presentation-Application-Domain-Infrastructure! Thank you very much for everything!

Comment: Updated my answer with the github repo.

Comment: @jpgrassi Super! Works like charm, I have successfully reorgranized my views! Thanks again, best wishes! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will help you solve the actual issue, since you will probably need to change lot of things.. but I find this structure more "clean" than what you have there. The problems I immediately see with this are:

- Hard to distinguish between actual features and setup/infra code. Is `Containers` a feature or something to do with Docker? Dunno, have to open it.
- The way it is now, in your `IViewLocationExpander` you have to "hardcode" each feature name because they are all spread around... not so cool.

My suggestion is to change the structure to:

- Features (Rename Views to Features, keep the Shared folder normally.)

  - Customer

    - Controllers
    - Views

Then, you configure your `ViewLocationExpander` like this:

```
public class ViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{

   public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        // {1} is Controller, {0} is View Name
        return new [] 
        {
            "/Features/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml", // Finds the Customer View folders
            "/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml", // finds the Home views.. they are in root of the folder.. so no need for Views
            "/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml" // Layouts
        };
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

This way, you can add new features, say like `Product`, with it's own `Views` folder and it will automatically be picked up. Here's an image of the structure I used in my setup:

[image]

**Edit:** Here is my solution on Github [joaopgrassi/custom-razorview-location](https://github.com/joaopgrassi/custom-razorview-location)

Also, I don't really get the point on having ViewModels in a separated project. The whole purpose of ViewModels are to serve the UI. There's nothing DDD on ViewModels, with public setters. Maybe I misunderstood you.. but I would definitely look more into that. DDD are rich, very often immutable entities.. and ViewModels are just poco classes just to transfer data around.